# How to create behavior like the $HOME variable

Tags: terminal, bash

I have grown to use the $HOME variable a lot.  So if I type `$HOME/` and hit TAB it will write out `/Users/user/`.  If I do a partial `$HOME/Down` and hit TAB it will write out /Users/user/Downlaods.  I love this.  But if I go into my .bash_profile and create a var like TOR='/media/torrents', then do `source /Users/user/.bash_profile` and try hitting TAB after typing $TOR it does not do this behaviour.

Can someone help me understand why?

update:
playing around it does work on MAC creating a variable with path `TOR='/media/torrents'`, on the command line doing $TOR/(notice the backslash) and hitting TAB it autopopulates.  This behaviour does not work on linux, centos in particular.

Comment: In your shell what does $TOR show + in your question you say $HOME/ and hit TAB but hitting TAB after typing $TOR . Why no / in the second case

Comment: I tried $TOR/ and it didn't work either.  I've tried every behaviour I can do with $HOME and I still cant get it to autopopulate like $HOME does

in the shell I can echo $TOR and it will how me the path.  but $TOR and hitting TAB nothing really happens

Answer (score 2):

You need to set a shell option for this

```
shopt -s direxpand
```

either directly on the command line or in your startup files.

From `man bash`

```
direxpand
   If set, bash replaces directory names with  the  results
   of  word  expansion when performing filename completion.
   This  changes  the  contents  of  the  readline  editing
   buffer.   If not set, bash attempts to preserve what the
   user typed.
```

Comment: thanks!
I don't see how I'm supposed to use this in my bash profile however?

Comment: Just add the code line - unfortuanately Stack Exchange does not highlight it